# IF Statement to Compare Two Files in Unix

Tags: unix, if-statement, scripting

I have a unix script, that will create the md5sum for two files and then check that the two files match.  This is an example of the script - but this is not comparing the files correctly - can anyone shed some light on this?

```
md5sum version1.txt >> file1
md5sum version2.txt >> file2

if [ $file1 == $file2 ]
then
    echo "Files have the same content"
else
    echo "Files have NOT the same content"
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [ "$(md5sum < version1.txt)" = "$(md5sum < version2.txt)" ]; then
    echo "Files have the same content"
else
    echo "Files have NOT the same content"
fi
```

If one of the MD5 checksums is already computed and stored in a text file, you can use

```
if [ "$(md5sum < version1.txt)" = "$(awk '{print $1}' md5hash.txt)" ]; then
...
```

Comment: @MichałPolitowski because the question uses it and the issue isn't with this specific detail which isn't strictly a bashism as it was first introduced by ksh IIRC. Corrected anyway

Comment: @jlliagre That's a bad reason, since `==` is only meant to be used with `[[`, the reason that it also works with `[` under e.g. `bash`/`ksh` is because they are (overly?) tolerant, but this might (will) break in other shells that follow the POSIX standard strictly and don't allow `==` with single-bracket notation. Just never use `[ ... == ... ]` (i.e., either `[ = ]` or `[[ == ]]`) to be on the safe/portable side, and educate others - don't just silently copy their mistakes :-) +1, though!

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I fully agree with you, the answers aren't only for the OP. `dash` for example would choke on `==`.

Comment: I like this version - nice and compact.  If I was supplying the MD5 check as a text file, how can I do this: `if [ "$(md5sum < version1.txt)" = "md5hash.txt" ]`

Answer (score 4):

```
HASH1=`md5sum version1.txt | cut -f1 -d ' '`
HASH2=`md5sum version2.txt | cut -f1 -d ' '`

if [ "$HASH1" = "$HASH2" ]; then
    echo "Files have the same content"
else
    echo "Files have NOT the same content"
fi
```

---

Alternatively:

```
if cmp -s version1.txt version2.txt; then
    echo "Files have the same content"
else
    echo "Files have NOT the same content"
fi
```

Comment: This is a good idea but you should use a hash function that is collision resistant. In MD5 you can "easily" find two files with the same hash but different contents. Consider using SHA-256 instead or another, more secure, hash function.

Comment: It's probably better to use `cmp` as a more direct solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
if [ "$file1" == "$file2" ]
then
    echo "Files have the same content"
else
    echo "Files have NOT the same content"
fi
```

Comment: That's just plain wrong, you are not comparing content there. In this case, just adding quotes doesn't fix the underlying problem.